# Can not install Ros Melodic, Why?

Tags: ubuntu, ros, ubuntu-17.10

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 on a virtual machine. I am trying to install Ros Melodic but when I try to follow the instructions provided, I get this error:

```
E: Unable to locate packages ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

I've tried the ros-shadow-fix solution but that does not work. I need help, please.

Answer (score 0):

I think something went wrong when you set up your sources or keys. Try to follow the following and let us know if everything works well.

**Setup your sources.list**

This is done in order to make your computer accept software from packages.ros.org.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

**Set up your keys**

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

**Installation**

Make sure your Debian package index is up-to-date:

```
sudo apt update
```

Check that all these commands are giving a successful output.